# Generate href list dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am implementing server side pagination in AngularJS following the code at [laravel-tricks](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/pagination-with-angularjs-and-your-api)

I pass pageNumber to the API and it returns the total number of results and other data on that page in the results. The data is then displayed in the table.

How can I generate a list of hrefs for pages dynamically when the results are received ?

Note 1: I have tried ngTable, but it doesn't update the table when the data is changed though it does update the model. Hence resorted to manual pagination since I need a basic pagination only

Note 2: I am not using Bootstrap there for pagination provided by AngularUI is not of any use.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why do you need hrefs in this example?  The pages are being loaded with AJAX.  Are you looking to implement URL routing?

Comment: I only want to show the pages numbered below the table so that the user may navigate directly to a page

Comment: I'd say just make `loadPage` take the page number, then add `<a ng-repeat='page in pages' ng-click='loadPage(page)'>{{page}}</a>`. Is there a reason you specifically need to generate `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
//Generate pagination buttons, each with the ng-click directive
<button ng-repeat="pageNumber in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" ng-click="goToPage(pageNumber)">
  <span ng-bind="pageNumber"></span>
</button>
```

Then have a `goToPage` function in your controller like this:

```
 $scope.goToPage = function(pageNumber) {    
     $scope.main.page = pageNumber;
     $scope.loadPage();    
 };
```

NOTE: I just used `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` as an example, but you may want to generate that array in your controller.

Comment: thanks I have a very large number of pages. (in hundreds). How to manage them in the ui ?

Comment: Maybe you could use a text input to jump to a page.  Maybe post the question here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/